# Updating files after RVM install

Tags: rvm

I have installed RVM enroute to updating and running different ruby and rails.  After install I received message to update shell's loading files.

> 1) Place the folowing line at the end of your shell's loading files
>        (.bashrc or .bash_profile for bash and .zshrc for zsh),
>        after all PATH/variable settings:

```
 [[ -s "/Users/eric/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/Users/eric/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM into a shell session.

 You only need to add this line the first time you install rvm.
```

I typed `[[ -s "/Users/eric/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/Users/eric/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`

and hit enter.  Does this update my files?  Or do I have to open some type of file and cut and paste code?

Since I did not see any notice as stated below from part 2 of the post install,  I closed the shell and opened a new one. but the RVM command does not seem to work.  Part 2 of the instructions post install was:

> 2) Ensure that there is no 'return' from inside the ~/.bashrc file,
>        otherwise rvm may be prevented from working properly.

This means that if you see something like:

```
'[ -z "$PS1" ] && return'
```

then you change this line to:

if [[ -n "$PS1" ]] ; then

```
# ... original content that was below the '&& return' line ...
```

fi # <= be sure to close the if at the end of the .bashrc.

# This is a good place to source rvm v v v
  [[ -s "/Users/eric/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/Users/eric/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM into a shell session.

EOF - This marks the end of the .bashrc file

```
 Be absolutely *sure* to REMOVE the '&& return'.

 If you wish to DRY up your config you can 'source ~/.bashrc' at the bottom of your .bash_profile.

 Placing all non-interactive (non login) items in the .bashrc,
 including the 'source' line above and any environment settings.
```

Thanks for the help as I am very new and trying to learn RoR but so far have not been able to get past the setup in many of the tutorials I've attempted.  It seems many [
[1](http://developer.apple.com/tools/developonrailsleopard.html)  [2](http://developer.apple.com/tools/rubyonrails.html)  are out of date with new software or I get error messages before I can even attempt to learn the code.  If someone knows of a good beginner tutorial that would be great.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The snippet that the installer gives you need to go in a file called the bashrc. The file lives in your home directory: /Users/eric/.bashrc

You need to edit this file and add the line from rvm and then you should be good to go.

As for getting rolling with rails I'd recommend The Pragmatic Programmers book on rails. You can find their books at pragprog.com

If you're on Ubuntu, my tutorial on setting rvm will get you roll all the way up to rails installation:

http://blog.dcxn.com/2011/06/20/setting-up-rvm-on-ubuntu-11-04/